# Ordering points along river in QGIS

Tags: qgis, rivers, order, stream-order, waterways

I found data on [water treatment facilities in the EU](http://discomap.eea.europa.eu/data/uwwtd/UWWTDmap_shapefiles_20171214.zip) (labelled in green on the map) and [stations that control for water quality in rivers](https://cmshare.eea.europa.eu/s/gBiXgqBCyBqBser/download) (labelled in black). I'd like to get a list of treatment facilities and water quality stations that are upstream and downstream for each treatment facility. Optimally the output would look something like the table below.

I'm new to QGIS and I'm not sure where to start solving the problem. Geodata on most rivers is available as MultiLineString in the dataset on the water quality stations (shown on the map). But I don't see how that could be used to get the information on which point along the river is upstream or downstream. Using the elevation of stations in basin areas to get the order of stations also seems not as a solution as different tributary rivers feed into larger streams.

[image: sample map]

| Treatment fac | Upstr treatment fac | Downstr treatment fac | Upstr stations | Downstr stations | River ID (optional) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DETP_SH60004 | DETP_SH60054; ... | ...? | DESM_SH_120889; DESM_SH_121434; DESM_SH_120017; ... | ...? | DERW_DESH_BR_10 |
| DETP_SH60054 | ...? | DETP_SH60004; ... | ...? | DESM_SH_120761;... | DERW_DESH_BR_08_C |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I think the best solution would be with a programmatic solution. Or you can try using networking solutions.

Comment: Something around shreve order amongst the river's streams and then inside a given river stream segment you use interpolation position along the line ... ? this could give you a relative position for any stations. And shreve order is a known method available in Qgis Grass i think